# What does Elevation in DrawShadow do exactly?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, skia

I know that [Flutter's `Canvas.drawShadow`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/eb05391962fb74e0152d6bb9827abdf341113de5/lib/ui/painting.dart#L4018) translates to [Skia's `SkShadowUtils::DrawUtils`](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/45d19fe063985c793b5c35534032923946c8fbf5/src/utils/SkShadowUtils.cpp#L541), where the `elevation` on the Flutter side affects the `zPlaneParams` on the Skia side (see the [`flutter::PhysicalShapeLayer::DrawShadow` engine implementation](http://34.94.103.149/classflutter_1_1_physical_shape_layer.html#ac5d99b79c8a24ca58446d601af248db9), which is called with `dpr` from [`Canvas::drawShadow`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/eb05391962fb74e0152d6bb9827abdf341113de5/lib/ui/painting/canvas.cc#L413) which is [directly called from Dart](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/eb05391962fb74e0152d6bb9827abdf341113de5/lib/ui/painting.dart#L4024)), however, I cannot at all figure out how **`elevation`** behaves when drawing a shadow in native (forget Flutter web because that is completely different again):

```dart
void drawShadow(Path path, Color color, double elevation, bool transparentOccluder) { // ...
  _drawShadow(path, color.value, elevation, transparentOccluder);
}
void _drawShadow(Path path, int color, double elevation, bool transparentOccluder)
                 native 'Canvas_drawShadow';
```

```cpp
void Canvas::drawShadow(const CanvasPath* path, SkColor color, double elevation, bool transparentOccluder)
{ // ..
  SkScalar dpr = UIDartState::Current()->window()->viewport_metrics().device_pixel_ratio;
  flutter::PhysicalShapeLayer::DrawShadow(canvas_, path->path(), color,
                                          elevation, transparentOccluder, dpr);
}
```

```cpp
void flutter::PhysicalShapeLayer::DrawShadow(...) {
   // ...
   SkShadowUtils::DrawShadow(canvas, path, SkPoint3::Make(0, 0, dpr * elevation),
       SkPoint3::Make(shadow_x, shadow_y, dpr * kLightHeight),
       dpr * kLightRadius, ambientColor, spotColor, flags);
 }
```

<sup>And so on - see the Skia source code link if you wish to dive deeper.</sup>

Precisely, I do not understand what range of numbers `elevation` accepts, i.e. what numbers I can put it - I would have assumed `0` to `600` looking at [`kLightHeight`](http://34.94.103.149/namespaceflutter.html#af5a46f83182e00e27bf950417af3ea2b), but that does not map completely to what I experienced. Even then, I still do not know what values for `elevation` ***mean***.
Additionally, I would love to understand how the size of the path and the canvas scale generally affects the shadow and potentially where the light source is located.
I need this information to ensure consistent behavior across different screen sizes.

So if anyone knows or can figure it out from the links I provided, I would gladly accept any input.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at `SkPoint3::Make(0, 0, dpr * elevation)` line of code.

I am sure that the value of `elevation` is used for determining how long/broad the shadow below the widget is going to be.

I don't think there's anything more to the `elevation` value.

If you find anything more than this, I am all ears. This is a really good question by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is basically what I know already because that is how *elevation* usually works (the docs mention [Material elevation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/elevation/)). I was wondering more about what range of numbers is accepted, how this elevation value is affected by the size of the path, and potentially where the light source is located because that is what I need to know if I want to ensure consistend behavior.

Comment: In case of light source you can always assume that the light source is on the top left end of  the device screen. Because that is where the origin(0,0) is and also on the opposite of that direction the shadow is cast.

Comment: but yeah, your question about size of path is one of core questios that I am wondering about my self